# Will the Angular Language Service work in VS 2017 build 15.9.7?

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I see various mentions of the Angular Language Service working only in a few editors.  I tried installing the npm package and restarting VS 2017 but I still get no intellisense within templates.  Is this feature just not there yet in VS 2017?

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/language-service
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the full answer yet, but the Angular docmentation (https://angular.io/guide/language-service#how-the-language-service-works) also says to modify your tsconfig.json with:

```
"plugins": [ { "name": "@angular/language-service" } ]
```

I still haven't got it working myself, but I figured I would post this to see if it helped.